# is it possible to consume marketing API in a mobile app?

Tags: flutter, facebook-ads

i want my mobile application (flutter) can create publicity campaigns and synchronize it with facebook Ads. i saw that it is the marketing API used for that but  i don't know if it is possible to consume the marketing API in my app.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to consume it with a mobile app:
   - Create a Facebook app and get an app ID. You use the ID to make API calls.
Use this [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis) to know how to do it.
You can use Graph API: The Graph API is the primary way to get data into and out of the Facebook platform. It's an HTTP-based API that apps can use to programmatically query data, manage ads and perform a wide variety of other tasks. Learn more in [Graph API Overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview) or start using in [Using the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/).
Here is how to send requests to [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/server-side-api/using-the-api#send).

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand and quickly search on [flutter packages page](https://pub.dev/packages), I guess you can use [facebook_audience_network](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network) package which is currently only available on Android devices.

As it is described in "Installing" section, you can use this package's dependency and import in your dart class in which you want to use it.